# Hello, I am using JDoodle to practice C programming, I created a fpointer to .text file, how can I open this .text file and see data?

Tags: c, file, fopen, fgets

I wrote this code in jdoodle, the screen is blank. How can I open the .text? Where did it go?

```
int main () {
    
    FILE * fpointer = fopen ("inventory.txt", "w");
    
    fprintf (fpointer, 
             "A432LIPG, Lipgloss\n A442LIPG, Lipgloss \n C465LIPG, Lipgloss");
    
    fclose (fpointer);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) is the opposite of `fprintf`

Comment: The text 'went' into the file "inventor.txt" that is in the working directory.  You should be able to open this with any text editor (e.g notepad++).  Hmmm, I take that back, I've never used JDoodle and I'm not sure where it puts files.  You might be better served by getting a compiler and install it on you system.  Then you can certainly create, save and open files.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly you need something like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) 
{
    FILE * fpointer = fopen ( "inventory.txt", "w" );

    if ( fpointer != NULL )
    {
        fprintf ( fpointer, "A432LIPG, Lipgloss\n A442LIPG, Lipgloss \n C465LIPG, Lipgloss" );

        fclose( fpointer );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( strerror( errno ) );
    }

    fpointer = fopen ( "inventory.txt", "r" );

    if ( fpointer != NULL )
    {
        enum { N = 100 };
        char s[N];

        while ( fgets( s, sizeof( s ), fpointer ) != NULL )
        {
            s[strcspn( s, "\n" )] = '\0';

            puts( s );
        }

        fclose( fpointer );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( strerror( errno ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case there is no need to strip the trailing newline and `s[strcspn( s, "\n" )] = '\0'; puts( s );` can be replaced with a simple `printf("%s" s);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri It is important to show that fgets appends the new line character.:)

Comment: My comment was for the OP :P ... of course you are right and is good to know that `fgets` appends a `"\n"`

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help, I will try!

Comment: @AekateriniZorbas I advice to close the question selecting the best answer.:)